# Importing Atmosphere packages

Tags: meteor, momentjs, atmosphere

I'm sorry if this question is stupid, Googling got me nowhere.

I want to install [MomentJS atmosphere package](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment)

I add this command to my `packages` file:

```
momentjs:moment
```

How do I use it? I've used every variation of this I can think of:

```
import {moment} from 'momentjs';
```

I've tried `momentjs/moment`, `moment/momentjs`, ... how do I use `moment`?

Comment: Nevermind I found it: http://guide.meteor.com/using-atmosphere-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

You have import like this :

```
import {moment} from 'momentjs:moment';
```

Basically you have to add full package name while importing.